# Do I include session.gc_maxlifetime on every page that needs to increase session timeout?

Tags: php

Just want to know if I want to increase session time out, do I need to include ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", 14400); on every page I call session_start()?

Thanks,

L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this in .htacces

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 14400
```

Comment: Correct, but if you did not have access to .htaccess then you would have to include it on every page before the call of session_start().